# HashTagHelper Creator() Has Private Access In?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add Hash Tags to my app in a textview. This is my first attempt doing this. I am struggling with this error. What does this want me to do? I don't understand this "Creator has private access in"? See below...

```
 public void HashTagHelper(TextView tv) {
    hth = new HashTagHelper.Creator(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.holo_green_light), new HashTagHelper.OnHashTagClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onHashTagClicked(String hashTag) {

        }
    });

    hth.handle(tv);
}
```

This is a red line under HashTagHelper.Creator

The error reads 'Creator()' has private access in 'com.volokh.danylo.hashtaghelper.HashTagHelper.Creator'

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It means that the class is private and you can't use it like this. Most likely, there's a static builder method you're supposed to call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Creator class has private constructor. And it's designed to be used as following: 
`HashTagHelper.Creator.create(color, listener)`

Comment: If that helps that please remember to mark this answer as a correct one, thanks.